# Need a query that switches columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I have this table:

```
 __________________________
| id1 | id2 | count | time |
|-----|-----|-------|------| 
| abc | def |   10  |   3  |
| abc | def |   5   |   1  |
| ghi | jkl |   2   |   3  |
+--------------------------+
```

id1 and id2 are varchar, count is int and time is int.

id1 and id2 together make the primary key.

Time can be 1,2,3,4 or 5 depending on when an item was added (NOT UNIQUE).

I want to write a query that gives me this output instead:

```
 _________________________________________
| id1 | id2 |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----| 
| abc | def |  5  |  0  |  10 |  0  |  0  |
| ghi | jkl |  0  |  0  |  2  |  0  |  0  |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Is that possible? I'm sittin here scratching my head but I cant figure it out!

Comment: Use Case and/or look up PIVIOT commands, that's what you're trying to do. (Depending on RDBMS etc)

Comment: if id1 and id2 alone were the primary key, your sample table would be impossible. Are you sure it's not id1+id2+count or id1+id2+time?

Comment: Yes it's possible! oh wait... that's not the answer your looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck. The rule for a **pivot** is that you still need to know the number and names of the columns in the result set without having to look them up at the time you run the query. As long as you know that, you're okay, and in this case your columns are restricted to the range 1 through 5.

There are a few ways to pivot like this. I still prefer the sum(case) method:

```
select id1, id2, 
    sum(case when time = 1 then [count] else 0 end) "1",
    sum(case when time = 2 then [count] else 0 end) "2",
    sum(case when time = 3 then [count] else 0 end) "3",
    sum(case when time = 4 then [count] else 0 end) "4",
    sum(case when time = 5 then [count] else 0 end) "5"
from [table]
group by id1, id2
```

Another optioin is the [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) keyword:

```
select id1,id2,[1],[2],[3],[4],[5] 
from [table]
PIVOT ( SUM([count]) FOR time IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) ) As Times
```

Comment: so much cleaner than a subselect.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select ID1, ID2, 
sum(f1) as '1',
sum(f2) as '2',
sum(f3) as '3',
sum(f4) as '4',
sum(f5) as '5'
from (  select ID1, ID2,
        case when time =1 then time else 0 end as 'f1',
        case when time =2 then time else 0 end as 'f2',
        case when time =3 then time else 0 end as 'f3',
        case when time =4 then time else 0 end as 'f4',
        case when time =5 then time else 0 end as 'f5'
        from dbo._Test
    ) as v
group by ID1, ID2
```

The inner query gives you columns for each time value, the outer query sums the values so you don't get two rows for the 'abc' + 'def' row.